# restangular and ruby on rails custom serialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am trying to use Restangular and Ruby on Rails.  I can return a model object, but I need to send down a custom object.  For example, if my model is person and it has 50 fields, and I just need name and `over21=true` if `age` is > `21`, how do I pass something like that down?  I am not sure how to customize a json object like that.

So instead of all of persons fields, just send down

```
[{name: 'Kyle', over21=true},{name: 'Jeff', over21:false}]
```